# animated background effect

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in my website which will animate two background images, transitioning them over one another and from left to right - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJKmn/.

Modifying  the HTML and CSS from the *codepen*, how would I be able to implement a cross-browser and device solution to work not only just in Opera and Firefox Mozilla, but also Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Apple's Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add browser prefixes like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eryni/